# Unexpected return of list of lists instead of list

Tags: python

This app will download a webpage and find all email addresses in the text of the page and return a list of them.

This is my current code:

```
def emails(content):
'return list of email addresses contained in string content'
    email = []
    content = urlopen(url).read().decode()
    pattern='[A-Za-z0-9_.]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_.]+\....'
    email.append(re.findall(pattern,content))
    print(email)
```

But for some reason I get:

```
[['somePERSON@university.ca"']]
```

instead of :

```
['somePERSON@university.ca']
```

Comment: Just a couple general suggestions: (1) Right now, your code doesn't return a list of email addresses, it prints them and returns None.  To return them, do `return email`.  (2) You don't really need to set email to be an empty list before you use it.  In fact, you could just `return re.findall(pattern, content)` and not even need the `email` variable.  (3)  Your function takes `content` as an argument, but it looks like you should be taking `url` as your argument.  Just my two cents. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`re.findall` actually returns a list, so you are appending a list to the list. You could do something like `email.extend(re.findall(pattern,content))` if you didn't want that behavior (although I usually do checks for matches on their own line to ensure that matches are found and non-matches are handled properly).

Comment: @JasonSchayer No problem, hope it helps.